# Entering for the third time in US under ESTA/VWP after two 90 days stays

Tags: usa, esta, repeat-visits, us-visa-waiver-program

I'm writing you as I would like to receive some information about entering in the US under the VMP.I'm an Italian citizen, living and working in Italy, and I entered in the US on December 26th and June 4th, which stays lasted 88 and 87 days, respectively, for both business and vacation purposes.

I searched for detailed information regarding how many days I am allowed to spend in the US under the VWP program - apart of 90 days per stay -, as well as what can be considered a reasonable amount of time between visits, without any luck.

Since I am planning to visit a friend of mine in the US for 9 days, may I ask you if it would be allowed or if there is any constraint that might prevent me to enter in the US? Would it be too risky?

Edit:
My question is slightly different than the older one because I'm concerned about entering in the US after **two** ~90 days stays in one year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no hard and fast rule regarding this; however, if trying to re-enter the US shortly after a long visit, the CBP officer is likely to assume you're trying to live in the US, in which case, unless you can convince him/her otherwise, you'll be summarily refused entry, deported and banned from entering under the VWP again.

Personally, I would wait at least 3 months, and bring solid documentation (letter from the employer, printout of return ticket, a formal invitation from your friend, documentation about the purpose of your previous trips, etc.) since then, you won't have spent more than 50% of the last half-year in the US

Comment: Thank you Crazydre. Because I spent June,  July and August in the US,  I think it is better to cancel the trip in order to avoid any potential issue.

Comment: @AlbertoVolpatto Notice that the half-year rule is my personal suggestion. The US doesn't have a 90/180 policy like the Schengen Area, the CEFTA states and some others. In theory, you could enter anytime, but like I said not a good idea